# Trouble running a scope function in angular test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

I have recently started trying to learn how to test angular. I have had some success but at the moment I am trying to test a directive and I cannot seem to make it work.

**Test code**

```
describe('navigation test', function(){
var element, location, route, rootScope, scope, httpBackend;
var elm;

beforeEach(module('myApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function($compile,$rootScope,$location,$httpBackend,$route) {


    location = $location;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    route = $route;
    $httpBackend.whenGET('partials/nav/nav.html')
        .respond(200);
    element = $compile("<navigation></navigation>")(scope);
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    scope.$digest();

}));

describe('Change page function',function(){
    it('should flip the location between /home and /test', function(){
        location.path('/home')
        scope.changePage();
        scope.$digest();
        expect(location.path()).to.equal('/test');
    })
})


});
```

**Directive function**

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp');

 app.directive('navigation', function($location, $q, $sce, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $mdComponentRegistry) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'partials/nav/nav.html',
    link: function(scope, elements, attrs) {

        scope.changePage = function() {
            if($location.path() == '/home') {
                $location.path('/builder')
            } else {
                $location.path('/home');
            }
        };
```

});
The error I am receiving is

**error message**

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

(evaluating 'scope.changePage()')

I cannot figure out why it cannot see the scope. Any help would be greatly appreciated. And if anyone could shed some light on angular testing that would be great.

Comment: obviously your directive wasn't applied to the scope. Please provide a plunker/jsfiddle

Comment: Does this not attach my directive to the scope? element = $compile("<navigation></navigation>")(scope); if navigation is my directive. If not how would I go about doing it?

Comment: I don't know - I just see a part of your directive.... / I don't see the name of the directive and also not in which module it is defined.

Comment: Updated question with directive code.

Comment: use wanna test the `mcqsApp` module, but the directive is defined in the `myApp` module

Comment: Yes that was my mistake. I was changing variable names before I put code up. This is up to date now and all names are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `$httpBackend.flush()` to serve the request to `partials/nav/nav.html` when you construct the `directive`. Just add it in and it should be working fine.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/jcf7pp2w/)